# Using timeout with docker run from within script

Tags: bash, docker

In my Travis CI, part of my verification is to start a docker container and verify that it doesn't fail within 10 seconds.
I have a `yarn` script `docker:run:local` that calls `docker run -it <mytag> node app.js`.

If I call the yarn script with `timeout` from a bash shell, it works fine:

```
$ timeout 10 yarn docker:run:local; test $? -eq 124 && echo "Container ran for 10 seconds without error"
```

This calls `docker run`, lets it run for 10 seconds, then kills it (if not already returned). If the exit code is 124, the timeout did expire, which means the container was still running. Exactly what I need to verify that my docker container is reasonably sane.

However, as soon as I run this same command from within a script, either in a `test.sh` file called from the shell, or if putting it in another yarn script and calling `yarn test:docker`, the behaviour is completely different. I get:

`ERRO[0000] error waiting for container: context canceled`

Then the command hangs forever, there's no 10 second timeout, I have to ctrl-Z it and then `kill -9` the process. If I run `top` I now have a `docker` process using all my CPU forever. If using `timeout` with any other command like `sleep 20 && echo "Finished sleeping"`, this does not happen, so I suspect it may have something to do with how docker works in interactive mode or something, but that's only my guess.

What's causing `timeout docker:run` to fail from a script but work fine from a shell and how do I make this work?

Comment: Try using docker -a as opposed to docker -i

Comment: Actually removing `-it` completely seems to have resolved this, and I don't actually need interactive mode to start my application. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like running docker in interactive mode is causing the issue.

Run docker in detached more by removing the -it and allowing it to run in default detached mode or specify -d instead of -it and so:

```
docker run -d <mytag> node
```

or

```
docker run <mytag> node
```